# Adding a Cisco RV084 appliance for site-to-site services in a local area network that I can't change

Tags: networking, cisco-vpn

I have a need to establish a site-to-site vpn connection to a remote office using a Cisco RV084 appliance.

We currently are in a shared office environment where our property manager has provided us with our own local area network.

There is a network switch but we don't have access to it - we essentially plug our network cables from the wall to our laptops/workstations - we get ip address that looks like this:

```
DHCP IP Address Range: 192.168.3.100 to 192.168.3.199
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.3.1
DNS: 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220
```

We are allowed to assign static ip addresses from `192.168.3.2` to `192.168.3.99` and from `192.168.3.200` to `192.168.3.254`.

I have asked our property manager to provision a DMZ ip for us - this would be `192.168.3.254`.

I was going to assign the WAN/EXTERNAL interface with the DMZ ip (`192.168.3.254`) but I'm not sure what I should assign the INTERNAL interface of this Cisco RV084 device.

Should I assign `192.168.3.253` to the INTERNAL interface of the Cisco RV084 device and then plug that into the wall.

For laptops/workstations that need access to server resources over the site-to-site vpn , I was going to just add a static route to those machines to use the `192.168.3.254` gateway instead.

Should that work?